# Most efficient way to write large amounts of data to file during loop

Tags: php

What is the most efficient way to write to file when a large amount of data is being generated and written during a loop.

The file is in xml format.

On each iteration of the loop around 6 lines are written to a file - equates to 3 xml nodes.

There are around 100,000 iterations to complete.

I am looking to find the most efficient in terms of speed first, and memory second. i.e. speed is of greater importance.

Comment: Some techniques could be recommended, but it will be much easier to see what you are currently doing and improve upon that

Answer (score 0):

Try storing a buffer of the data, and then if the buffer is full write all of the buffer.

pseudocode:

```
$buffer

for (conditions) {
   if (buffer->full) {
       write to file
   } else {
       add to buffer
   }
}
```